# LDAP on Ubuntu 16 won't connect

Tags: ldap, openldap, slapd

I've installed LDAP on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine, using this command:

```
sudo apt install slapd ldap-utils
```

This is my config file `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf`

```
#
# LDAP Defaults
#

# See ldap.conf(5) for details
# This file should be world readable but not world writable.

BASE    dc=domain,dc=local
URI     ldap://domain.local:389

#SIZELIMIT      12
#TIMELIMIT      15
#DEREF          never

# TLS certificates (needed for GnuTLS)
#TLS_CACERT     /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

I've checked status of LDAP, it's running, and I don't have any firewall running at all on the server in question:

[image]

However, when I run `ldapsearch -x` it tells me:

> ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)

Here is the debug output:

```
ldap_create
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP domain.local:389
ldap_new_socket: 4
ldap_prepare_socket: 4
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 192.168.9.74:389
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 4 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect: 
connect errno: 111
ldap_close_socket: 4
ldap_err2string
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

Here is my hosts file, and if I ping that domain it returns the IP:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.9.74    domain.local
```

Answer (score 0):

`ldapsearch` simply cannot open a TCP connection to 192.168.9.74 port 389.

There could be many reasons for that (excluding the ones you already excluded in your question):

- firewalls in between
- *slapd* does not really listen on IP address 192.168.9.74 (check with `netstat -tulpn`)